# errors when compiling with adMob V2 (Error retrieving parent for item / UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:)

Tags: android, xml, admob

I am having these type of error in admobs B4A 5.50

```
IDE - Process timeout: 600
Javac.exe: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\javac.exe
Android.jar: C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-15\android.jar
B4A bridge: v2.13
Phone: Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9305)
System: Android 4.4.4
Libraies: Core (v4.92) and Admob (V2.0)
```

Running as Debug, I get this error:

```
B4A version: 5.50
Parsing code. (0.00s)
Compiling code. (0.05s)
Compiling layouts code. (0.00s)
Generating R file. Error
c:\android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced similar type of issue in android in these You need to increase MaxRamForDex: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/posts/58036/

It will solve problem